# Ninject - class depends optionally on a class that cannot be resolved

Tags: c#, ninject, code-injection

Let's say I have a class SoundCard

```
public interface ISoundCard 
{ 
}
class SoundCard : ISoundCard
{
    public SoundCard() {}
}
```

I have another class Mp3Player that depends on SoundCard class.

```
public interface ISoundPlayer
{ 
}
class SoundPlayer : ISoundPlayer
{
    [Inject]
    public SoundPlayer(ISoundCard SoundCard)
    {
    }
}
```

I have a third class MusicPlayer that depends optionally Mp3Player.

```
class MusicPlayer
{
    [Inject]
    public MusicPlayer([Optional]ISoundPlayer soundPlayer)
    { }
}
```

These class are bound this way :

```
Bind<ISoundCard>().To<SoundCard>().InSingletonScope();
Bind<ISoundPlayer>().To<SoundPlayer>().InSingletonScope();
Bind<MusicPlayer>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

When I get MusicPlayer, as expected, it works.

```
var musicPlayer = YdsNinject.Get<MusicPlayer>();    //OK
```

But now let's say I decide not to bind SoundCard.
It is expected that Mp3Player can't be resolved by Ninject.
But as MusicPlayer has a optional dependency on Mp3Player, I expected that

```
  kernel.Get<MusicPlayer>();
```

still works OK with a null injection for MP3Player.
But it's not the case, I get an exception.

Note : Mp3Player intentionally don't depend on SoundCard with an [Optional] attribute (because I decide that the Mp3Player should not exist if there is no sound card)

How to avoid the exception and get a null injection in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `WithConstructor` binding. Ninject will try to use the most specific constructor, ie the one with the most parameters. In your case it will try to use the constructor with a parameter & fail because it can't resolve the parameter. The `WithConstructor` binding tells it which constructor to use - the one without the parameter, or with a null parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your `MusicPlayer` class to have two constructors:

```
class MusicPlayer
{
    public MusicPlayer()
        : this((ISoundPlayer)null)
    { }

    public MusicPlayer(ISoundPlayer soundPlayer)
    { }
}
```

As Simon Halsley stated, Ninject will choose the constructor which has the most parameters it can resolve (which you have overriden by the `[Inject]` attribute).

However, i would suggest that you have a look at the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#C.23), i think it might be a good fit here (long story short: instead of doing a lot of `if (foo == null)` create a "null" implementation which does nothing).